# Detecting when App Store is unavailable while processing a purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

While I'm processing a purchase, I want to be able to detect if Apple's servers have stalled and pop up an alert saying apple's servers are unavailable.  Sounds easy, right?  The issue I'm running into is that I'm not sure there's a way to tell if Apple's servers have stalled, or the user is just sitting on Apple's 'Confirm Your In-App Purchase' alertview.  This basically happens in this delegate method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

Checking the transactionState for the array of transactions, the delegate is called on SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing when the purchase is initiated, and SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased after the purchase has completed.  There's no indicator for when this alert dialog pops up and if the user confirms, so I can't reliably pop up an 'unavailable' message in these cases.

Am I missing something, or is this correct?  How are others handling this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transaction fails following method is called :

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
    {
       NSLog(@"The error description is:%@",[transaction.error description]);
        if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorUnknown)
        {
            // error!
           //Your time to take over
        }

     }
```

You should check http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Why check for SKErrorUnknown?  Wouldn't I still want to take action in this case?

Comment: did you see the link i posted..there are cases when user would has clicked cancelled in the iTunes pop up,,,if i click i do not want to buy...should i get a pop up..cant connect to iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

failedTransaction can get called because of different reasons. if you are looking for specific to store is down then this is what I am doing in all the store kit callbacks.

Look in the Error code returned by Store Kit

```
if ( [[error domain] isEqualToString:SKErrorDomain] 
{  
    if ([[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"cannot connect to itunes store"] )
    {  
       // Show custome message to user that store is not available  
    }  
}
```

There is one more condition you can add in if, just to make sure --- >

```
[error code] == 0
```

Sorry for the formatting I never get it right. :)